# Julias Pkg.develop wont take into account changes that I have made

Tags: package, julia, environment

I have a script, main.jl, I am trying to run that looks like this:

```
using Pkg
Pkg.develop(path="path/to/MyPackage/")
import MyPackage as mp

mp.test()
```

In my function located in "path/to/MyPackage/src/test.jl" I have

```
function test()
  println("test 1")
end
```

If I run main.jl I see "test 1", however if I keep the REPL open and modify test() to print out "test 2" it still prints out "test 1". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I have found that using the `Revise` package in Julia helps resolve this issue. All I need to do is add `using Revise` to the top of the document:

```
using Revise
using Pkg
Pkg.develop(path="path/to/MyPackage/")
Pkg.instantiate()
Pkg.resolve()
import MyPackage as mp

mp.test()
```

After that I can make changes to `test()` and they show up each time I run the script.

Note that I found that this doesnt work unless I put `using Revise` at the top before I load any of the packages I want to develop into the REPL, meaning that I had to restart the REPL once to make sure that I imported `Revise` before running any `Pkg.develop`.

Comment: I believe it is enought that `Revise`  is loaded before the package(s) you want to modify. I also suggest to leave the pkgs that you want to develop in the default folder `~/.julia/dev/`